# centering nested div not working within bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this markup:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
    <h1>BLOG POST TITLE</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>

           </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm expectiong that the content within `col-md-6` to be centered inside the `col-md-12` but this is not happening. I've tried also with `margin:0 auto;` but the same result.

Here is a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/T94GB/2/)

How can I center the content of `col-md-6` within `col-md-12` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an offset for the inner element, in Bootstrap, by default, all rows have 12 cols.

```
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
          ...
        </div>
```

Further details in official doc: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting